# Selectively plotting functions using Manipulate

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, inequality

I'd like to plot the solution region to a system of linear equations, but I want to be able to plot one equation at a time (and then "layer" them) instead of all at once. I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that using the Manipulate function. Do I use CheckboxBar? Here's what I have so far:

```
points1 := Table[{i - 1, j - 1}, {i, 70}, {j, 70}]
Show[ListPlot[points1, PlotRange -> {{0, 70}, {0, 70}}, ImageSize -> 850,
AxesLabel -> {"Racing Cars", "Sport-Utility Cars"}, PlotStyle -> 
Directive[RGBColor[0.45, 0.67, 0.82, 0.82], PointSize[0.005]], LabelStyle ->
Medium],
RegionPlot[{R <= 40, S <= 60, R + S >= 70}, {R, 0, 70}, {S, 0, 70}, 
PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]]
```

What I *don't* want is to have the ability to plot *only* one equation at a time. E.g.,

```
Manipulate[Plot[function[frequency*x + phase], {x, -6.6, 6.6}], {frequency, 1, 5}, 
{phase, 1, 10}, {function, {Sin, Cos, Tan}}]
```

(Sorry, newbie here... I promise that I did do a thorough Google search, but none of the examples I found have been helpful to my situation.)

Many thanks!

Comment: see here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11274/how-to-connect-a-checkbox-with-part-of-the-graphics

Comment: Thanks, @agentp! I tried this solution, but something's not working (see below). What am I doing wrong?

Manipulate[
 Show[ RegionPlot[R <= 40, {R, 0, 70}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[plot1]],
  RegionPlot[S <= 60, {S, 0, 70}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[plot2]],
  RegionPlot[R + S >= 70, {R, 0, 70}, {S, 0, 70}, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[plot3]]],
 {{plot1, 1, "R \[LessEqual] 40"}, {0, 1}, 
  Checkbox}, {{plot2, 1, "S \[LessEqual] 60"}, {0, 1}, 
  Checkbox}, {{plot3, 1, "R + S\[GreaterEqual]70"}, {0, 1}, Checkbox},
  ControlPlacement -> Left]

Comment: I'd suggest asking on the other site..more expertise.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment in the post has a syntax error. `RegionPlot` needs at two variables defined.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  RegionPlot[R <= 40, {R, 0, 70}, {S, 0, 70}, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[plot1], Orange}],
  RegionPlot[S <= 60, {R, 0, 70}, {S, 0, 70}, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[plot2], Blue}], 
  RegionPlot[R + S >= 70, {R, 0, 70}, {S, 0, 70}, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[plot3], Brown}]
  ],
 {{plot1, 0, "R <= 40"}, {0, .5}, Checkbox},
 {{plot2, 0, "S <= 60"}, {0, .5}, Checkbox},
 {{plot3, 0, "R + S >= 70"}, {0, .5}, Checkbox},
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.